# I had a girlfriend, whom I didn't want to leave

Tags: writing

I am trying to translate Osamu Dazai's essay 如是我聞(Thus I heard from the Buddha) into English.

The original text belongs to the public domain: http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000035/files/1084_15078.html

You can read about the author here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osamu_Dazai

You can read parts of my translation here: http://lang-8.com/1483508

Here is a part of my translation:

http://lang-8.com/1483508/journals/9913466692196417769822852313093409740

> To tell the truth, I lied to him.
>   I had a girlfriend at that time.
>   I didn't want to leave her. That's why I declined the proposal with a fake reason.
>   I had big troubles with this girl later, but I don't regret my decision.
>   I even think that having troubles together with a poor stupid girl is more difficult and nobler an enterprise than going abroad.

My question is about the following sentences in the above.

> I had a girlfriend at that time.
>   I didn't want to leave her.

Someone told me that these should be rewritten as follows.

> At that time, I had a girlfriend, whom I didn't want to leave.

I wonder which is better.

**Remark**
The previous paragraph of the above is as follows.
http://lang-8.com/1483508/journals/215960620314216056838140082359796270126

Comment: As a native speaker, I don't really see a real difference between the two options. I will say that hardly any native speakers use *whom* anymore, and instead use *who* for both the objective and subjective cases. In this case *whom* is used correctly, just contrary to typical style of native English speakers.

Comment: Since your question involves translation, why not add the original passage (in Japanese) that is the source of your translated paragraph? There may be some hidden meaning. However, in a storytelling timeline, "At that time" is often used as an introductory phrase.

Comment: *having troubles together with a poor stupid girl*   -- it is not clear what you mean to say by "having troubles together".  Are boy and girl united and facing a challenge together, or is each having issues with the other? I think you probably mean the latter, in which case we would not use the word "together".

Comment: also *more difficult and nobler an enterprise* strikes my ear as ungrammatical.

Comment: @TRomano "also more difficult and nobler an enterprise strikes my ear as ungrammatical."
Interesting. I wonder why no native English speakers corrected it in Lang-8.

Comment: Perhaps because it a different construction (the more x...the more y) it would be grammatical.  "*The* more difficult and nobler an enterprise, *the* more devoted we should be to it."   As it stands, it reads "Having troubles....is more difficult ... an enterprise than...."

Comment: @TRomano
Here is a quote by Barney G. Glaser(you can google about him).
Experts versus Laymen: A Study of the Patsy and the Subcontractor
"Thus, as choosing becomes more imminent, the handling of people becomes more pronounced.
Handling people at this stage can easily become more difficult a task than comparing,
which mostly is a fairly straight forward calculation."

Comment: @Makoto Kato: Unlike your sentence, Glaser's is not complicated by having *two* comparative adjectives, one of which uses "more" and the other the **-er** comparative ending. "...more difficult and nobler an enterprise".

Comment: @TRomano Would you please elaborate on what is wrong with that?

Comment: @Makoto Kato: To keep that aspect of the question distinct, I suggest you ask it as a a separate question on this site: `Is "it is more difficult and nobler an enterprise" ungrammatical?`

Comment: @TRomano I opened the following thread as you suggested.
http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/90624/is-it-is-more-difficult-and-nobler-an-enterprise-ungrammatical

Regards,

Comment: @TRomano You suggested I ask it as a separate question. I did as I was told and I have been expecting you would answer the question.

Comment: You received a good answer there. Inflectional comparatives (-er ending) are restricted to internal position.  "nobler an enterprise" has "nobler" in *external* position.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I prefer your wording over Someone's alternative. Yours is simpler, more direct, and fits better with the overall tone of the paragraph. If you wanted, you could make it a single sentence by using conjunction:

> I had a girlfriend at that time and didn't want to leave her.

Another possible improvement (although improvements, like beauty, are in the eye of the beholder) would be to change *at **that** time* to *at **the** time*; *at the time* is a standard adverbial phrase meaning:

> [**at the time**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/time?a=british) at the particular point when something was thought of or done

So, you could also write:

> I had a girlfriend at the time and didn't want to leave her.

In this case, though, I'd disregard the advice you're getting from Someone.

Answer (score 1):

To me, "I had a girlfriend, whom I didn't want to leave" sounds awkward. 
I prefer either your original two-sentence version, J.R.'s rewritten version using "and," or a version without the comma:

> At that time, I had a girlfriend who(m) I didn't want to leave.

I'm struggling to figure out why I prefer this. I assume you've heard the general "rule" about using a comma before relative clauses: it is used before "non-defining" relative clauses, but not before "defining" relative clauses.

While it seems logically possible for this to be a non-defining relative clause, it doesn't sound right to my ears. I think it has to do with "a girlfriend" being an indefinite noun on its own.

Comment: I don't know why you find 'whom' awkward. It sounds pretty normal to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to prefer Someone's wording. It seems more ... awkward ... to me. It's not wrong, but your version isn't wrong either.